# BxSlider stop issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I'm using BXSlider for a simple slideshow and I was wondering if there was a way to stop the slider when you click on the 'next' or 'previous' button. I've figured out a way to stop it on mouse over but is there a way to do the same when you either click on next or click inside the slide? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a listener to the controls and use that listener to stop the slideshow.

```
var slider = $("#slider").bxSlider();

$(".slider_control").click(function(e){
    slider.stopShow();
});
```

One way you could capture all clicks (on the control and the slider itself) is to wrap the slider and the controls in an outer div and then listen for clicks that bubble up.

```
<div class="slider_wrap"><!-- put slider here --></div>
<script>
    var slider = $("#slider").bxSlider();

    $(".slider_wrap").click(function(e){
        slider.stopShow();
    });
</script>
```